# Error when compiling biopython1.65: error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, debian, installation, biopython

I am trying to install biopython 1.65 in debian. I have the dependencies Numpy and Scipy. 
When I try to build it, it fails:

`python setup.py build`

`running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'Bio.cpairwise2' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Bio/cpairwise2module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Bio/cpairwise2module.o
Bio/cpairwise2module.c:12:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.`
`error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`

Somebody know how I can solve it?

Many thanks

Comment: does `/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h` exists? if no, you must install package libpython2.7-dev

Comment: it doesn't exist. I tried to install this package and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "Python.h"
```

tells the preprocessor to search a local file, and if it doesn't exists there, the preprocessor changes it to

```
#include <Python.h>
```

which should be located in `/usr/include/python2.7` (which is passed as argument to gcc). Many Linux distros don't have header files installed by default, so you have to install it manually.

Header files for `python2.7` are shipped with package `libpython2.7-dev`

You can find which package to install by searching it with `aptitude`, `synaptic` or `apt-cache search` adding `dev` after the package name (in that case `python dev`); the name could be different than the installed one.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on Fedora, what helped was:

```
yum install python-devel
```